# cookies rest when send cURL request php

Tags: php, curl, cookies, request, setcookie

When I send cURL request and then try to use cookies that I saved in the last request it doesn't show up like it doesn't save in cookies at all:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://restapi.com");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $_COOKIE["data"] = $response;
        setcookie("data", $response, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
```

In second time page reload ($_COOKIE["data"]) is NULL although $_COOKIE["data"] is must contain $response string

Comment: Well then most likely `$response` was actually NULL when you reload the page … You are overwriting `$_COOKIE["data"]` with that value each time.

Comment: No.. I tried to print `$response` before `$_COOKIE["data"] = $response;` and I got the response content , so `$response` isn't NULL

Comment: Well then _when and where_ is the cookie actually NULL? And what have you done to try and debug this so far? Have you checked if the proper response header to set the cookies is received on the client? Have you checked whether the client sends it back with the next request?

Comment: Ok after `setcookie("data", $response, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));` `$_COOKIE["data"]` it's has content , but when I try to reload the page and print `$_COOKIE["data"]` in the beginning before  `$ch = curl_init();` I get NULL

Comment: And now for the rest of what I asked …

Comment: Yes I checked ... for the response header I receive it , but in the next request the client didn't send it back agian

Comment: Well then your browser likely did not accept it to begin with, due to some of the “parameters” not matching (rather unlikely, because you don’t specify a domain or path to restrict it), or something else - privacy extensions, browser default settings - preventing it.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe that's right the browser doesn't accept the response..